# 3n+1 sequence with "for loop"

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is code I wrote

```
def seq3np1(n):
    count = 0

    while(n != 1):

        if(n % 2) == 0:        # n is even
            n = n // 2
            count += 1

        else:                 # n is odd
            n = n * 3 + 1
            count += 1
    return count

def main():

    num = int(input("what number do you want to put?: "))
    start = int(input("Number for upper bound: "))
    for i in range(1, start+1):
        count = seq3np1(num)
    print("This is the starting number: ", num)
    print("Number of iterations:", count)

main()
```

What I need to do is:

• Ask the user for a value to use for the upper bound of your range

• Create a for loop using an iteration variable called start that provides values from 1 up to (and including) the user supplied upper bound.

• Call the seq3np1 function once for each value of start.

• Write a print statement that prints the value of start and the number of iterations.

but my function does not call the seq3np1 function for every value of start.

Did I do something wrong with my for loop function?

Also, I need to create graphing data. However, am I supposed to use setworldcoordinates function in main function? or do I create another function for graphing?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to print the `count` in the for loop and call `count = seq3np1(i)` instead of `seq3np1(num)`.

```
def main():
    start = int(input("Number for upper bound: "))
    for i in range(1, start+1):
        count = seq3np1(i)
        print("Number of iterations:", count)
```